# storing password in source

Tags: cryptography, passwords, password-protection

I have read several places now which basically advise against storing a password in source code, and I understand the reasons.

I have two apps: one for encryption and one for decryption. Data is encrypted to a file on a server; this file is downloaded and decrypted on a client's machine, and then processed by a proprietary app (not mine). The data is sensitive and, (ideally) is meant to be only accessible to the processing app.
As it stands I am using a symmetric key algorithm since the data is large enough. The password is hardcoded into the source code as a string - I know, bad for several reasons.

What I would like to know is what's the best way to store the password? My thought is to use an asymmetric key algorithm e.g. RSA, just for the password, but can't wrap my head around how to do this and if it even makes sense in my scenario. I'd prefer not introduce another file for distribution. I don't know much about decompiling, but I figured implementing a PBKD into the client app would pose the same problem. Cryptography is new to me as you can tell, and using this great forum.

Comment: So you want your program to have the data, but the user not? Then don't send the data to the client at all. Do the processing on the server.

Comment: openSSL would be a good library  option for cryptography..https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/crypto.html

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on how to implement openssl https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-openssl/

Comment: And how will OpenSSL help here? Right, not at all. [Btw, did you miss that Crypto++ is already used?] It's impossible to keep data on the users computer secret from the user. And a program on the user computer has a key, it's impossible to keep the *plaintext* a secret.

Comment: We don't really know the threats you are trying to defend against, so its hard to say what you should be doing and how you should be doing it. You should probably visit [Secure Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) and [Secure Password Storage paper](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g) by John Steven of OWASP before you go any further.

Comment: Does the user need to enter a password or authenticate before the data is encrypted/decrypted or does this happen automatically behind the scenes with the hard coded password?

Comment: @deviantfan Not possible to process on the server in this case unfortunately.

Comment: @jww Thanks, I'll take a looksie.  I'm only focusing on acquiring the pwd from memory or decompiling the source.  The decrypted data can quite easily be acquired, but ideally want to limit there so they don't have carte blanche access to decrypt _all_ other encrypted files.

Comment: @TheBadger Happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use symmetrical keys in source files. You can use RSA without introducing another file. As opposed to symmetrical keys, the public key can be hard-coded in source code without any security issues, iff you can guarantee the integrity of the source file. Then again, if someone manages to change it, decryption won't work or there is a man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack going on (and you wouldn't know about it).

CAVEATS

- This approach suffers from susceptibility of a MITM attack. An appropriate countermeasure would be to sign the data, but then you are stuck handling the keys and is really a separate question.
- Keys are not forever, the key-pair you generate needs to be rotated from time to time.
- Make the keys big enough (at least 2048 bits).
- Revocation needs to be done manually by you. If you need a more automated solution, consider looking at PKI and OSCP Responders (with or without stapling).
- If the data you are sending is large, RSA operations will be lengthy.

Ok, with that out of the way, let's dig in. The example code is written entirely with JDK 8.

First, generate a key-pair. This needs to be done once or every time you need to rotate:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

byte[] pubEnc = publicKey.getEncoded();
byte[] privKeyEnc = privateKey.getEncoded();

System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pubEnc));
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privKeyEnc));
```

Let's say the public key was (these are actual keys I generated, **don't** use these):

```
private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_BASE64 = 
"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCGue
5TCdPJt08w7crbvWjfcSUy/xXjzjjjjPDP7D8PNSnn
CUeNcGWsR/Pd3eoBjmrAy/4Rl8JlHylRry8pX7Zpcz
iQB8wWQdpkSoArjeu4taeFn/45+eg4J5mzmIzFG9F5
wF7N+SeSvtq3E3Q0mtJRRZZJYgNkFmeDuOQjljJVZw
IDAQAB";
```

and the private key was:

```
private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_BASE64 = 
"MIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl8wggJbAg
EAAoGBAIa57lMJ08m3TzDtytu9aN9xJTL/FePOOOOM
8M/sPw81KecJR41wZaxH893d6gGOasDL/hGXwmUfKV
GvLylftmlzOJAHzBZB2mRKgCuN67i1p4Wf/jn56Dgn
mbOYjMUb0XnAXs35J5K+2rcTdDSa0lFFlkliA2QWZ4
O45COWMlVnAgMBAAECgYBAWTIRi1ISuHEkh48qoS8j
+eCwmNGVuvvFA55JUSdVVikrZm08iwCk5sD9qW6JS8
KFT2mMcZWxws5za171PffbeHoIFaNI5n5OXJa4meZA
cgl4ae5su89BjvfzDF2gsnBHwLpgsT0aVdIDQ5BGtL
WzRwZCogY6lZhBOQZAaNFYIQJBALr2+kT+pkSlxrrR
tMxK7WL+hNO7qOIl/CTBuAa6/zTtoEjFMFQBY//jH+
6iabHDfKpaFwh6ynZTXZsb7qIKOM8CQQC4eRAH1VEo
iofZNnX3VjiI5mLtV8rc8Jg+wznN+WFnwdNoLK8y9t
EcuKxg3neIJAM70D6l0IhBfza1QAqQh4/pAkA5vyLZ
wJV2SoWxGihvmQztMJOyGho1j2nrqHHAkm1U2bhSAa
XFrJBIbsxkFoHyx+BvdVf75IE4PtOAnwX7wpB9AkBQ
7CKBHS2N+D8hpQdYqcUBIPdyoFmIVC6lEaTw2x3Ekz
027KsqUyVmUQilMdIDsbCNc4uX14N+H90S43X+8sjJ
AkAKsvRbZ0Au9JytSRKSB7vYl37283zHoQ5jyYUE7x
g7C6nWSl1GEa6khZ47hFAj9C2bdLJ6GtjTleFsVCsR
LUoG";
```

*The keys above are line wrapped for formatting reasons.*

Let's say `args[0]` was `"attack at dawn!"` and you client looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   byte[] pubKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(PUBLIC_KEY_BASE64);
   PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKey));

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
   Cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
   String encryptedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(args[0].getBytes("UTF-8")));
   System.out.println("Encrypted data is: " + encryptedData);
}
```

> Output: Encrypted data is:
>   cDoPpQYc6qibrBl5jdENcV+g6HslQDlo9potca5rQxecnxR3Bd/e1T0njqUMACl7x7AG3foGxqZyyUIMrOVXcnw/ux7BgQcg+RDZhSVFQAd5kUGI96pw8WtDVo1N1+WEfaaPhK9CpwUKUxtwR0t27n+W0vhFCqNTEGhofLt8u9o=

The server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  byte[] privKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(PRIVATE_KEY_BASE64);
  PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKey));

  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
  byte[] encryptedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(args[0]); 
  byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
  System.out.println("Decrypted message was: " + new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8"));

}
```

> Output: Decrypted message was: attack at dawn!

One cool thing about the JDK's RSA implementation is that it uses Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding (OAEP) from PKCS#1, which has the effect that even identical messages will look different from each encryption.

Like previous commenters have mentioned, without seeing the full picture, there may be other security problems to address. But for what it's worth, I think this approach is better than using symmetrical keys, which still can be used with this encryption scheme. Then you would get what's called a *hybrid cryptosystem*, but there are APIs that do this for you.

Comment: Great example, and thanks for the advice!  I think in my case though it's the reverse scenario: the server only encrypts, and the client only decrypts, no other communication.  The decrypted data is processed on their local machine from another process (not mine).  Considering this, wouldn't the private key have to be with the client?  Which is fine, except in the hands of the wrong person, I want to limit the access to that plaintext alone.

Comment: Hmm. Because of the usual inherent asymmetry in a client-server model (many clients and few servers), only encrypting data destined for the client sounds like a bad idea. The private key would have to be distributed to an environment (the client's) you usually don't have any control over. And if you put it in the source code, there's only one key, which makes it highly vulnerable. If that is the case, I would consider using Diffie-Hellman instead of RSA. You would still be susceptible to MITM attacks but on the other hand, you would get PFS (Perfect Forward Secrecy).

Comment: Sweet, I'll look into that.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of storing the plaintext password in the source and checking against that you can store the encrypted password in the source (hard coded).

Then the user can enter the password, the code encrypts the password and compare the result of the encryption with the stored encrypted value to see if the password match. The password entered (not the encrypted password) is then used to encrypt/decrypt the data.

The encryption used should make the effort to reverse the encrypted password to the plaintext password hard/impossible.

Example:

1. You choose the encryption/decryption password to be `This is my password1` (the one that is currently in the sources).
2. You encrypt the password with for instance SHA-256 and hard code it in the source: `9845735b525fa70b2651975022a44be268af1d4defadba9ab2a0301e0579534c`.
3. Encrypt/decrypt app prompt for password.
4. User enter password.
5. App calculates the SHA-256 of the entered password and compare the result to `9845735b525fa70b2651975022a44be268af1d4defadba9ab2a0301e0579534c`
6. If it matches the data is encrypted/decrypted with entered password `This is my password1` using your code already in place.
7. If it does not match, give an error.

A hacker gets your sources and have access to the hash `9845735b525fa70b2651975022a44be268af1d4defadba9ab2a0301e0579534c` and the algorithm you used. But he needs the `This is my password1` password to decrypt the data. He can reverse or brute force the hash but that takes effort and time.

One can use seeds etc, but to keep them secret is then again the same issue.

It is probably not the most secure, I am no expert but it is better than having `This is my password1` in the sources.

Comment: a) RSA is not a hash. b) MD5 is not secure at all. c) No hash needs to be reversed if everything is on the client device. It's much easier than that. d) If the hash is encrypted, and the key is in the program too, why encrypt at all?

Comment: @deviantfan I understand what you mean and have updated my answer to make it more clear what I wanted to say, does it help?

Comment: Not really, because a) an encryption like you described in the last sentence doesn't exist, b) the key has to be somewhere if it is an encryption, and c) like already said, it doesn't help at all, because an attacker doesn't need to reverse something irreversible.

Comment: a) hard to reverse does exist, like SHA-256, yes the hacker can brute force it but is the data worth more than the time to brute force? "SHA-256 algorithm generates an almost-unique, fixed size 256-bit (32-byte) hash. Hash is a one way function – it cannot be decrypted back" [source](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator). A seed will make it  more secure, but is it really needed... The hacker must either reverse the hash or brute the password before he will be able to decrypt the data, how else?

Comment: But SHA256 is not an encryption, and it has no "password"/key to encrypt some other data. ... "Almost unique" is completely nonsense; there are *infinite* possible plaintext for every possible hash value. ... Seeding some data meant to be encrypted is also nonsense. ... Please, just learn more about this stuff, this are the lowest basics of cryptography.

Comment: About your steps in the answer: a) The hash between password-entering and encryption doesn't make it stronger, and the whole hardcoded thing isn't even necessary in your scheme. To get some improvement, see PBKDF2 etc. b) Until now I understood the question that way that the user isn't allowed to get the data... nothing you said helps for this purpose in any way.

Comment: @TheBadger I get your drift and thanks for the input.